# Win 7 in virtualbox that already runs in virtualbox?

Tags: virtualbox

Can you install win 7 in virtualbox that already runs in virtualbox of a nother win 7? Question also implies for any other operating system.

Answer (score 0):

Each virtual machine is technically "independent" of one another, and with VirtualBox, you could easily do this, since it is supported on both Windows and Linux host operating systems (emulated or not). You could simply use Windows as your "base-host" OS, run Linux in a VM, and then use that operating system as the new base-host for Bochs.

check this out
[HERE](https://superuser.com/questions/312433/can-you-run-one-virtual-machine-inside-another)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not fully clear to me. If you mean running a virtualized Windows 7 within a native Windows 7, this is perfectly possible, as any other OS/OS combination. It will just eat up a lot of ressources. If you mean running a virtualized Windows 7 within another virtualized Windows 7, then you will run into trouble and you would better run the 2 virtualized Windows 7 in parallel on a single native OS.